# Ffmpeg ignoring -itsoffset?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm combining two image sequences side-by-side into a single video. The first of these sequences needs to run for the entire duration of the video, but the second sequence should begin after 50 seconds.

I'm calling ffmpeg as follows:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 25 -i ./sequence1/frame.%04d.png -f image2 -r 25 -itsoffset 00:00:50 -i ./sequence2/frame%05d.png -filter_complex '[0:v]pad=iw+300:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=1620:0[vid]' -map [vid] -c:v libx265 -crf 23 -preset slow output.mp4
```

Unfortunately, ffmpeg seems to be ignoring my `-itsoffset` argument (or I'm misunderstanding how this argument operates?) as both sequences start at the beginning of the video.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `-itsoffset` option must been applied when input contains Timestamps. your inputs are picture and have no timestamp, so `itsoffset` option has no effect on them.

1-To your goal :

Picture based stream that has been delayed, must been converted to video stream: `ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 25 -i ./sequence2/frame%05d.png -c:v libx265 -crf 23 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p ./sequence2/sequence2.mp4`

Now you can use this `mp4` file instead of second sequence with `itsoffset` option.
`ffmpeg -f image2 -r 25 -i ./sequence1/frame.%04d.png -itsoffset 00:00:50 -i ./sequence2/sequence2.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:v]pad=iw+300:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=1620:0[vid]' -map [vid] -c:v libx265 -crf 23 -preset slow output.mp4`

2- To note:

in this scenario we have one encoding and decoding cycle that causes some quality loss. but it's not too much to worry about.

`-r` and `-framerate` are not same options, and in these cases you would better use `-framerate` instead of `-r`